# PHP While statement is showing same results as the queryresult

Tags: php, mysql, function, if-statement

I'm having a little bit of trouble with my PHP function. In the database I get 2 results back from my query. But my function is doing something else. It changes when I edit '=' to '=='

MySQL Query:

```
SELECT ContentPages.ContentPagesID, ContentType.ContentTypeName
FROM `ContentPages` INNER JOIN ContentType ON ContentPages.ContentTypeID = ContentType.ContentTypeID INNER JOIN ContentInformation ON ContentPages.ContentInformationID = ContentInformation.ContentInformationID
```

Result:

```
ContentPagesID                  ContentTypeName
01425d4a-2abd-11e4-b991-525400  products01
014269dd-2abd-11e4-b991-525400  information01
```

PHP Function:

```
function GetAllPages() {
$GetAllPagesSql = "SELECT ContentPages.ContentPagesID, ContentType.ContentTypeName FROM `ContentPages` INNER JOIN ContentType ON ContentPages.ContentTypeID = ContentType.ContentTypeID INNER JOIN ContentInformation ON ContentPages.ContentInformationID = ContentInformation.ContentInformationID";
    $GetAllPagesQuery = mysql_query($GetAllPagesSql);
    while (($GetAllPagesRow = \mysql_fetch_array($GetAllPagesQuery)) != false) {
        if($GetAllPagesRow[ContentTypeName] === 'product01') {
            DisplayProducts01DesignFunction();
        }
        else if ($GetAllPagesRow[ContentTypeName] === 'information01') {
            DisplayInformation01DesignFunction();
        }
    }
}
```

When I change:

```
if($GetAllPagesRow[ContentTypeName] = 'product01') {
    DisplayProducts01DesignFunction();
}
else if ($GetAllPagesRow[ContentTypeName] = 'information01') {
    DisplayInformation01DesignFunction();
}
```

To this:

```
if($GetAllPagesRow[ContentTypeName] === 'product01') {
    DisplayProducts01DesignFunction();
}
else if ($GetAllPagesRow[ContentTypeName] === 'information01') {
    DisplayInformation01DesignFunction();
}
```

It goes from showing function `DisplayProducts01DesignFunction()` twice to `DisplayInformation01DesignFunction()` once.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: = is the assignment operator == is equality operator,=== is the absolute equality operator which you dont need.Use ==

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should actually be running it only once if your code is fixed. When you change that `==` to `=` that then doesn't remain a comparison and becomes an assignment which results to `TRUE` and hence your if block gets executed, which is wrong.

```
if($GetAllPagesRow[ContentTypeName] = 'product01')
```

Is not the correct way to write an  if condition, if you are making your code run fine using that logic then you're doing it wrong. That `=` should be `==`

When you say

```
if($GetAllPagesRow[ContentTypeName] = 'product01')
```

Then that if block will always be executed even if you have 100 rows.

**Now you might** ask ok when I put `==` then why doesn't the first if block work anymore? Its because you are comparing a wrong string, your database contains `products01` and your `if` contains `product01`, see the missing `s`. Your actual `if` condition should be

```
if($GetAllPagesRow[ContentTypeName] == 'products01') {
    DisplayProducts01DesignFunction();
}
else if ($GetAllPagesRow[ContentTypeName] == 'information01') {
    DisplayInformation01DesignFunction();
}
```